# how to use var_dump function

Tags: php

I am trying to output the information about a particular variable of decoded json those being tags but am having difficulty outputting anything I get syntax error unexpected bracket after var_dump statement what do I need to add / change thanks all

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array(); 
$json = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test.json'); 

if($json!=null){ 
$decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
//$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
//$ss=$decode["array"]; 
//echo $decoded['number']; 

if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
    foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
    //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

  { 
var_dump($configurationItems['tags']);


}
```

}

```
?>
```

Comment: The if(is_array... needs to be closed also, last bracket is for the foreach

Comment: I think is better for you to start writing code using a free IDE (that automatically highlights many errors like yours).

Comment: This question and [another of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941198/undefined-index-mysqli-ston) may show that a lack of indentation is making the structure of your code confusing for you. You need to develop something of an OCD tendency regarding the neatness of your code, including switching on invisible characters in your editor, so you can check your tabs/spaces are nigh-on perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use inside the for each

```
foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
{
var_dump($configurationItems['tags']);
}
```

OR

```
var_dump($decoded["configurationItems"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have following errors:

- close statements with a `;`
- Need to close if's bracket `}`

Try this code:

```
if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
    foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
    { 
      var_dump($configurationItems['tags']);//Corrected
    }//End of foreach

}//End of IF
```

Comment: I have tried your code thankyou but I am getting an unexpected end of file error

Comment: Have you used `}?>` ??? You should put space between them try `} ?>`. And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482527/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-in-my-php-code

Comment: I did thanks still no luck what might help is if you look at this question which gives more info about why i'm doing what i am doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022131/undefined-index-name